# Android share firestore data with entire app

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

My MainActivity has a TabView that gets populated by 4 Fragments, each Fragment uses Firestore DocumentReference to get data, which causes my app to download the data again for every TAB. I would like to get the data in the DocumentReference in my MainActivity and share that DocumentReference between my 4 Fragments and even a different Activity. 
Is this possible? 
My Firestore DocumentReference contains objects, so I'm not certain if it would work with Shared Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

With the Android Firestore SDK, [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) is enabled by default.  This means that when a document is fetched, it will stay in a local cache on the device and will not be downloaded again for subsequent access (unless the document has changed on the server, or it was evicted from the cache because the cache grew too large).

For your case, I doubt that you're actually fetching the document multiple times, unless you disabled persistence.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate class for Firestore Operations.

```
 public class FirebaseUtils {
        public static DocumentReference getFirestoreUserDocRef(String documentName) {
            return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(documentName);
        }
    }
```

And you can access anywhere in your project.

Hope it helps you.